# Why use git reset here instead of git merge?

Tags: git

In a textbook on Git, I found this command prompt blurb explaining how a developer might typically react to an emergency situation where he has to temporarily table his current line of development to fix an error. I'm confused about its ending:

```
$ cd the-git-project

# edit a lot, in the middle of something
# High-Priority Work-flow Interrupt!
# Must drop everything and do Something Else now!

# Create new branch on which current state is stored.

$ git checkout -b saved_state
$ git commit -a -m "Saved state"

# Back to previous branch for immediate update.

$ git checkout master

# edit emergency fix
$ git commit -a -m "Fix something."

# Recover saved state on top of working directory.

$ git checkout saved_state
$ git reset --soft HEAD^

# ... resume working where we left off above ...
```

Consider those last two (i.e., `git reset --soft HEAD^` followed by `git checkout saved_state`).

Why on earth would the developer get back to his old work state by this means? Wouldn't it be a better practice to just merge `saved_state` into his master branch?

My first question notwithstanding, what is the point of executing `git reset --soft HEAD^` here? Assuming the developer makes changes to his liking at this location in his commit graph (i.e., at the merge-base between these two branches, in his "saved-state" branch), what would he then do afterwards to incorporate these changes with his most up to date master branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) He doesn't want to merge because the work on branch `saved_state` was only half way done and potentially unstable, so no way to merge it back to `master`

2) `git reset --soft HEAD^` : to get back exactly at the state he was:

- The `--soft` only resets the stage
- `HEAD^` means previous revision before `HEAD` in that case

So his working directory is the same as at the beginning and his status will highlight him the changes he made when he "monkey commit"

But, he could have `git stash save -u` ... simplier and cleaner (IMHO).

Comment: So basically, he gets to the exact same state he was in before the interruption AND he gets to discard the "monkey commit" (which is probably not clean enough to want to commit to the official history of his project). Is this about right (aside from the fact that `git stash` might have been a better approach)?

Answer (score 3):

First:  in this scenario, **they do not want to merge their work.** They are still *working* on it, so it would be ***very*** counterproductive to merge anything from that branch in.

To me, this looks like a poor man's [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing), which would cover this scenario and use case much nicer.

Let's look at the flow:

- on branch saved_state
- commit work to saved_state
- on branch master
- commit fix to master
- on branch saved_state
- Move all commits from the tip of saved_state into the index

Second:  `git reset --soft` allows you to take whatever commit you specify and place it back into the working index, as if you hadn't committed that work before.  `HEAD^` is merely going to get the last commit you had done.

Again, it's kind of like a poor man's `git-stash`, which would be ten times simpler to execute:

- on branch saved_state
- stash work
- on branch master
- commit fix to master
- on branch saved_state
- unstash (pop or apply) previously stashed changes